# What's the best way to store an object and its features in clojure?

Tags: clojure

An object has at least its position and dimensions but potentially other fields, eg.

```
(def obj1 '(cup1 x 0 y 0 z 0 width 10 height 10))
(def obj2 '(cup2 x 0 y 0 z 0 width 10 height 10))
(def objs '(obj1 obj2))
```

What's the most efficient way to store these type of objects if I want to access and modify values, compare their names or dimensions and allow me to potentially add new fields in the future?

Is there something like an ordered dictionary like in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the fields are of equal importance, then a [list of maps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62551448/823470) is great, but finding a single object will be slow since you'll have to walk through the whole list looking for it. If the "name" of each object is a unique/primary key then you could use a map of maps instead for very easy (and fast) lookup of individual objects by their names.

```clj
(def objs
  {"cup1" {:x 0 :y 0 :z 0 :width 10 :height 10}
   "cup2" {:x 0 :y 0 :z 0 :width 10 :height 10}})

;; retrieve by name (will error if name is not found)
(get objs "cup1")

;; add (will replace any existing obj with the same name)
(assoc objs "cup3" {:x 0 :y 0 :z 0 :width 10 :height 10})

;; remove (will not error even if name is not found)
(dissoc objs "cup3")

;; update by name (will error if name is not found)
(assoc-in objs ["cup1" :x] 5)

;; get all objects without names (i.e. list of maps)
(vals objs)

;; get all objects with names
(map (fn [[n obj]]
       (assoc obj :name n))
     objs)
```

Note that everything in Clojure is immutable unless otherwise specified, so all the above operations will result in a separate data structure, leaving the original untouched. Nothing is actually being "updated" or "overwritten" or "removed" - Clojure is simply returning you the view of what the data would look like if those things were done.

The main Clojure website has a section dedicated to [domain modelling using maps](https://clojure.org/guides/learn/hashed_colls#_representing_application_domain_information).

To convert the data structure in your question into this map of maps, you could:

```clj
;; from question
(def obj1 '(cup1 x 0 y 0 z 0 width 10 height 10))
(def obj2 '(cup2 x 0 y 0 z 0 width 10 height 10))
(def objs '(obj1 obj2))

;; since '(obj1 obj2) contains merely symbols, not references to obj1 and obj2,
;; it will be necessary to store it like this instead:
(def objs [obj1 obj2])

(defn map-keys
  "Applies function f to each key of map m.
   Ex: (map-keys inc {1 100 2 200}) -> {2 100 3 200}"
  [f m]
  (reduce-kv (fn f-of-k [acc k v]
               (assoc acc (f k) v))
             (empty m) m))

(defn symlist->map
  "Converts the OP's symbol list into a keywordized map with a stringified name.
   Ex: (symlist->map '(a x 1)) -> {:name \"a\" :x 1}"
  [symbol-list]
  (update (map-keys keyword
                    (apply hash-map (conj symbol-list 'name)))
          :name str))

(def obj-lookup
  (->> objs
       (map (comp (juxt :name identity) symlist->map))
       (into {})))

;; now you can
(get obj-lookup "cup1")
```

The above converts the name to a string, but you can leave names as symbols by removing the `(update ... :name str)` from `symlist->map` (and you can leave even the property names as symbols by removing the `(map-keys keyword ...)`). In fact nearly anything can be a key in a Clojure hash map (even entire other maps, although that wouldn't be a common use case) as long as the things correctly implement `hashCode` and `equals`.

If for whatever reason you need to get back to the original structure, something like this will work:

```clj
(map (fn [[obj-name obj-properties]]
       (seq (reduce (fn symbolify-entry [acc [k v]]
                      (conj acc (symbol k) v))
                    [(symbol obj-name)] obj-properties)))
     obj-lookup)
```

And obviously it's even simpler if you had decided to leave all keys as symbols everywhere, because no conversion back to symbols is needed:

```clj
(map (fn [[obj-name obj-properties]]
       (conj (flatten (seq obj-properties)) obj-name))
     obj-lookup)
```

Comment: That's great! Yes the names are unique. How would I convert my existing list of objects into this map of maps?

Comment: The conversion seems to work and returns objs as `{cup1 {:x 0, :height 10, :y 0, :name cup1, :width 10, :z 0}, cup2 {:x 0, :height 10, :y 0, :name cup2, :width 10, :z 0}}` but none of the above operators work e.g. `(get objs 'cup1)` returns nil ?

Comment: @tar why using list of objects-maps? why not a map of maps?

Comment: @user3710760 because `objs` hasn't changed. If you want you can def a new variable with the output of my code, e.g. `obj-lookup` then you can `(get obj-lookup 'cup1)`. However I realize I didn't convert the name symbols to strings; I'll update the answer a bit

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim if you are referring to `obj1` and `obj2` and `objs`, I am using those because they are what the OP has in their question. My code is showing how to transform those into a map of maps.

Comment: @tar ah true, sorry, didn't got that - looked to quickly over and not to the end.

Comment: @tar so it's not possible to have symbols as keys?

Comment: @user3710760 it absolutely is! Feel free to remove the `(update ... :name str)` and then the output will retain the name as a symbol. In fact there is a wide range of types that can be keys in a map.

Comment: I have a last question (not sure if I should create a new post for this): How do I convert the map of maps back into the original nested list with the name as the first item (and ideally the others in the same order too, but not necessarily)

Comment: also so `:x` is not symbol but a keyword, right? is it possible to change it to a symbol or does it need to be a keyword?

Comment: for converting it back, I did this: `(map #(concat (list (key %)) (flatten (into () (for [[k v] (val %)] [(symbol k) v])))) objs)`

Comment: `map-keys keyword` can be removed - that is what changes the symbols to keywords. You'll find that symbols are rarely used in Clojure compared to keywords, because keywords carry more meaning and can be used as functions.

Answer (score 1):

A Clojure map is very commonly used for such things, often with Clojure keywords as keys, but the keys can be strings, symbols, numbers, vectors, etc., any immutable Clojure values:

```
(def obj1 {:name "cup1" :x 0 :y 0 :z 0 :width 10 :height 10})
(def obj2 {:name "cup2" :x 0 :y 0 :z 0 :width 10 :height 10})
(def objs [obj1 obj2])
```

Clojure maps are unordered, and have very fast lookup by key to get the corresponding value, and fast "update", meaning "return a new map with one or several keys having new values associated with them", by the function `assoc`, and several other built-in functions.

There is a third-party library that provides maps that remember the insertion order of the key/value pairs relative to each other, but they are seldom used by Clojure developers: https://github.com/clj-commons/ordered

Comment: Thanks. If objs is a vector, how would I retrieve for cup1? Is this the right way? `(filter #(= "cup2" (% :name)) objs)`

Comment: and how would I edit the obj instance in the objs list since they are immutable in clojure?